# Refactor query to work with MySQL (unknown column error)

Tags: mysql, sql

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `deleted` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userVersion` (
  `userId` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `effective` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`, `effective`, `created`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`)
);
```

The query I'm trying to perform:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN userVersion uv
  ON u.id = uv.userId
  AND uv.effective = (
    SELECT MAX(uv1.effective)
    FROM userVersion uv1
    WHERE uv1.userId = u.id
    AND uv1.effective <= NOW())
  AND uv.created = (
    SELECT MAX(uv2.created)
    FROM userVersion uv2
    WHERE uv2.userId = u.id
    AND uv2.effective = uv1.effective
    AND uv2.created <= NOW())
```

I'm getting an unknown column error of `uv1.effective` (situated right before the last line). I believe this query works for other databases (e.g. Oracle) but doesn't seem to work with MySQL. How could I change this query to get the same behavior?

PS: The `created` column is supposed to represent when the row was inserted in the database while `effective` is supposed to represent when that row should start being used (this allows me to add changes in the present that will work in the future).